# Fastest Way To Calculate Directory Sizes

Tags: linux, file-io, filesystems

what is the best and **fastest** way to calculate directory sizes? For example we will have the following structure:

```
/users
      /a
      /b
      /c
      /...
```

We need the output to be per user directory:

```
a = 1224KB
b = 3533KB
c = 3324KB
...
```

We plan on having tens maybe even hundred of thousands of directories under /users. The following shell command works:

```
du -cms /users/a | grep total | awk '{print $1}'
```

But, we will have to call it N number of times. The entire point, is that the output; each users directory size will be stored in our database. Also, we would love to have it update as frequently as possible, but without blocking all the resources on the server. Is it even possible to have it calculate users directory size every minute? How about every 5 minutes?

Now that I am thinking about it some more, would it make sense to use node.js? That way, we can calculate directory sizes, and even insert into the database all in one transaction. We could do that as well in PHP and Python, but not sure it is as fast.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I have gone back and marked answers.

Comment: None of answers are marked as accepted.

Comment: Just a note that `$ du -sh` takes a very long time for me for a 500GB folder.

Answer (score 7):

Why not just:

```
du -sm /users/*
```

(The slowest part is still likely to be `du` traversing the filesystem to calculate the size, though).

Answer (score 4):

What do you need this information for? If it's only for reminding the users that their home directories are too big, you should add *quota* limits to the filesystem. You can set the quota to 1000 GB if you just want the numbers without really limiting disk usage.

The numbers are usually accurate whenever you access anything on the disk. The only downside is that they tell you how large the files are that are *owned* by a particular user, instead of how large the files *below his home directory* are. But maybe you can live with that.

Comment: We need it for billing. We are billing on disk usage. Also, we want users to be able to see how disk space they are using in their control panel, as real time, as possible.

Comment: In that case I would rely on the numbers given by the disk quota system. And if you don't trust them, you can still calculate the actual disk usage once a day to see if the two numbers differ. But be aware that things such as hard links may make it difficult to compute the disk usage accurately. The built-in disk quota system already takes care of all that.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
du -cm --max-depth=1 /users | awk '{user = substr($2,7,300);
>                                   ans = user ": " $1;
>                                   print ans}'
```

The magic numbers 7 is taking away the substring /users/, and 300 is just an arbitrary big number (awk is not one of my best languages =D, but I am guessing that part is not going to be written in awk anyways.) It's faster since you don't involve greping for the total and the loop is contained inside du. I bet it can be done faster, but this should be fast enough.

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple cores you can run the du command in parallel,

For example (running from the folder you want to examine):

`>> parallel du -sm ::: *`

`>> ls -a | xargs -P4  du -sm`

[The number after the -P argument sets the amount of cpus you want to use]

Answer (score 1):

not that slow but will show you folders size: du -sh /* > total.size.files.txt

Answer (score 1):

Fastest way for analyze storage using `ncdu` package:

```
sudo apt-get install ncdu
```

command example:

```
ncdu /your/directory/
```

Comment: `ncdu` is way *way* faster than `du`.